# Reordering dropdown items script not working in IE

Tags: jquery

I added a script to automatically reorder dropdown items alphabetically, however it is not working in IE (tested in IE9). It does work in other browsers, please see below:

```
<select class='whatever'>
<option value='e'>Hello</option>
<option value='c'>Banana</option>
<option value='d'>Sugar Cane</option>
<option value='b'>Palm Oil</option>
<option value='a'>Apple</option>
</select>

<script>
var options = $('select.whatever option');
var arr = options.map(function(_, o) {
    return {
        t: $(o).text(),
        v: o.value
    };
}).get();
arr.sort(function(o1, o2) {
    return o1.t > o2.t ? 1 : o1.t < o2.t ? -1 : 0;
});
options.each(function(i, o) {
    console.log(i);
    o.value = arr[i].v;
    $(o).text(arr[i].t);
});
</script>
```

You can see a demo version of this here: http://jsfiddle.net/jelane20/eQR3C/

Thank you for your help!

Comment: It seems to work in IE 11...

Comment: It Works fine in IE9 too... Check Again

Comment: @Jenny It is that even your fiddle doesn't work in IE9?

Comment: Weird.... For me in IE9 it does not work....unless I have the developer console open, then it does.

Answer (score 0):

Might be due to the console is not defined. Can you try commenting out the console.log for the moment? Have below code on top of your js to handle this globally.

```
if (!window.console) { 
    window.console = {
        log: function(obj){}
    };
}
```